# How to change page layouts of all pages from a 2010 to 2013 migration?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout

From what I researched, when you migrate from 2010 to 2013, you are supposed to make new page layouts based on the new format. But the problem is, if I am migrating from 2010, that means I am importing the content database, so all the pages from 2010 already has page layouts. So I am wondering, if I make new page layouts, how would I change the pagelayouts of those pages from 2010 to the new 2013 page layouts? How would the zones match up? What would I need to do to ensure it can be done?

Can anyone explain this?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is confusing for me. All the page layouts should work fine while migrating from SharePoint 2010 to 2013. If you have created a new page layout you need to set them manually for each page. Can you please provide the reference you have searched that "when you migrate from 2010 to 2013, you are supposed to make new page layouts based on the new format. ".

Comment: Old page layouts are aspx files, but in 2013, I saw they are html files, that SharePoint automatically makes aspx files from it. So after migrating, I can only modify the aspx files and not html?

Comment: As per my poor knowledge, the HTML files are associated with master pages. For example, oslo.master has a oslo.html file too. Page layouts are still single with aspx extension. Please correct me if i am wrong. I have just migrated the sites from 2010 to 2013 and nothing bad happened with page layouts. They all worked fine in 2013.

Answer (score 0):

As far as editing page layouts in 2013, it's the other way around.  With Design Manager you create the HTML page layouts and utilize the code snippets available there, SharePoint will then take those and create the ASPX pages.  You edit the HTML not the ASPX pages.  In fact - there should be a comment in the file telling you not to modify it, if it was created by the Design Manager.

In terms of migrating, you don't have to mess with page layouts if you are using SharePoint pages.  The only time this will be an issue during the migration is if you have custom page layouts.  In this case you need to evaluate how to handle them, and most likely need a tool like MetaLogix to help map custom layouts to 2013 layouts.

Comment: Yeah, we have custom page layouts. What happens if we migrate them to 2013? Would it migrate fine or do we actually need to make new page layouts, and then the problem is how to convert each of the pages to the new page layouts...

Comment: No quick answer there.  Do a test run first, and validate the results. If there are errors  you'll need to decide how to address those (change layouts before migration, or use a tool to map to new layouts).  Metalogix has a free tool that can do this for up to 50GB of data.